# data not submitted by this code in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

This is php of my form and i want to use it in wordpress would anybody help me to solve this? i m new to wordpress its not submiting any data to table give some action path to the form i dont know where the errors are by this code i am not able to submit the form

```
    //protect your codes from attacks.
     if ( isset($_POST['exporter']) ? $exporter=$wpdb->escape($_POST['exporter']) : $exporter=''
     isset ($_POST['importer']) ? $importer=$wpdb->escape($_POST['importer']) : $importer=''
isset($_POST['dateissue']) ? $dateissue=$wpdb->escape($_POST['dateissue']) : $dateissue='';
   //..
 }
    if (!$wpdb->insert('wp_form_data',

                            array(
                                'consignor'=>$_POST[exporter]
                                ,'consignee'=>$_POST[importer]
                                ,'conveyance'=>$_POST[conveyance]
                    ,'origin'=>$_POST[origin]
                    ,'entry_port'=>$_POST[dpoe]
                    ,'importing_country'=>$_POST[impcon]
                    ,'container_no'=>$_POST[container]
                    ,'package_no'=>$_POST[nopk]
                        ,'package_type'=>$_POST[tyop]
                    ,'product_name'=>$_POST[name]
                    ,'bot_name'=>$_POST[botname]
                    ,'quantity'=>$_POST[quantity]  

,'certify'=>$_POST[certify]                                 ,'add_declaration'=>$_POST[declaration]
,'date'=>$_POST[date]

                                ,'treatment'=> $_POST[treatment]
                                ,'duration_temprature'=>$_POST[dutemp]
                                ,'concentration'=>$_POST[concen]
                                ,'add_information'=>$_POST[adinfo]
                                ,'inspector_name'=>$_POST[insname]
                                ,'place'=>$_POST[place]
                                ,'name_designation'=>$_POST[namedesg]
                                ,'issue_date'=>$_POST[dateissue]
                            ))) exit;
    else {echo 'Form Submitted';}
    ?>
```

Comment: The syntax of `if ( isset($_POST['exporter']) ? ...` looks odd.

Comment: It is a mixture of statements @lc :D

Comment: Make sure you not getting any fate Error on that page . put `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` on top of the page.

Comment: Tell me what `warning/notice/errors` you are getting after enabling `display_errors` to 1

Comment: What output it prints ?  why are you putting `Form Submitted` in else part ? Your code make no sense. `else` is not intended with `if`

Comment: Code seems like `PHP` will cry for ever

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ...\wp-content\plugins\allow-php-in-posts-and-pages\allowphp.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 2

Comment: @Sahal can you make it correct for me?

Comment: Try the code below and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code (As you mentioned the code above itself is having lots of issues. Donoo about the whole page has how many) - `Seems like you are lacking of basic PHP skills. Spend a week to learn **PHP** before going to have a sky level PHP`

```
<?php
//no need to connect &amp; close to db. it's done automatically by wpdb.
global $wpdb;
//protect your codes from attacks.
isset($_POST['exporter']) ? $exporter=$wpdb->escape($_POST['exporter']) : $exporter='';
isset($_POST['importer']) ? $importer=$wpdb->escape($_POST['importer']) : $importer='';
isset($_POST['conveyance']) ? $conveyance=$wpdb->escape($_POST['conveyance']) : $conveyance='';
isset($_POST['origin']) ? $origin=$wpdb->escape($_POST['origin']) : $origin='';
isset($_POST['dpoe']) ? $dpoe=$wpdb->escape($_POST['dpoe']) : $dpoe='';
isset($_POST['impcon']) ? $impcon=$wpdb->escape($_POST['impcon']) : $impcon='';
isset($_POST['container']) ? $container=$wpdb->escape($_POST['container']) : $container='';
isset($_POST['nopk']) ? $nopk=$wpdb->escape($_POST['nopk']) : $nopk='';
isset($_POST['tyop']) ? $tyop=$wpdb->escape($_POST['tyop']) : $tyop='';
isset($_POST['name']) ? $name=$wpdb->escape($_POST['name']) : $name='';
isset($_POST['botname']) ? $botname=$wpdb->escape($_POST['botname']) : $botname='';
isset($_POST['quantity']) ? $quantity=$wpdb->escape($_POST['quantity']) : $quantity='';
isset($_POST['certify']) ? $certify=$wpdb->escape($_POST['certify']) : $certify='';
isset($_POST['declaration']) ? $declaration=$wpdb->escape($_POST['declaration']) : $declaration='';
isset($_POST['date']) ? $date=$wpdb->escape($_POST['date']) : $date='';
isset($_POST['treatment']) ? $treatment=$wpdb->escape($_POST['treatment']) : $treatment='';
isset($_POST['dutemp']) ? $dutemp=$wpdb->escape($_POST['dutemp']) : $dutemp='';
isset($_POST['concen']) ? $concen=$wpdb->escape($_POST['concen']) : $concen='';
isset($_POST['adinfo']) ? $adinfo=$wpdb->escape($_POST['adinfo']) : $adinfo='';
isset($_POST['insname']) ? $insname=$wpdb->escape($_POST['insname']) : $insname='';
isset($_POST['place']) ? $place=$wpdb->escape($_POST['place']) : $place='';
isset($_POST['namedesg']) ? $namedesg=$wpdb->escape($_POST['namedesg']) : $namedesg='';
isset($_POST['dateissue']) ? $dateissue=$wpdb->escape($_POST['dateissue']) : $dateissue='';
$data = array( 'consignor'=>$_POST[exporter]
        ,'consignee'=>$_POST[importer]
        ,'conveyance'=>$_POST[conveyance]
        ,'origin'=>$_POST[origin]
        ,'entry_port'=>$_POST[dpoe]
        ,'importing_country'=>$_POST[impcon]
        ,'container_no'=>$_POST[container]
        ,'package_no'=>$_POST[nopk]
        ,'package_type'=>$_POST[tyop]
        ,'product_name'=>$_POST[name]
        ,'bot_name'=>$_POST[botname]
        ,'quantity'=>$_POST[quantity]
        ,'certify'=>$_POST[certify]
        ,'add_declaration'=>$_POST[declaration]
        ,'date'=>$_POST[date]
        ,'treatment'=> $_POST[treatment]
        ,'duration_temprature'=>$_POST[dutemp]
        ,'concentration'=>$_POST[concen]
        ,'add_information'=>$_POST[adinfo]
        ,'inspector_name'=>$_POST[insname]
        ,'place'=>$_POST[place]
        ,'name_designation'=>$_POST[namedesg]
        ,'issue_date'=>$_POST[dateissue]
    );
if (!$wpdb->insert('wp_form_data', $data)) {
    echo "Form Submitted and Inserted";
} else {
    echo 'Form Submitted';
}
```

Comment: Can you paste full code here ? Above code I mentioned won't sent any error.

Comment: it becomes too long by 6703 characters :( can you give me email id i mail it to you or any other palce where i can upload it?

Comment: link for the entire code https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RoWPrHIIWQU0t1XrbuxFKT1QfSEGYEbStFphXisvbdI/edit

Comment: sahal006@gmail.com. Sent a mail

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in ...\wp-content\plugins\allow-php-in-posts-and-pages\allowphp.php(373) : eval()'d code on line 6

Comment: its also adding blank data